# How can I create a relative URL location for my form?

Tags: html, forms, relative-url

I'm learning about forms in HTML. At the moment I've written this part of my code:

```
<form action="results_page.txt" method="get">
<p>Favourite Colour:
    <input type="text" name="f_colour" size="15"
     maxlength="20" />
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is use a blank local text document on notepad to receive peoples favourite colours.

At the moment I'm getting the error on Microsoft Edge:

"
Hmm, we can’t reach this page.
Try this
•Make sure you’ve got the right URL: ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/dnserror.html#file:///F:/HTML_practice_results.txt?username=aklsfj
"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

p.s. I am quite new to HTML so if I am asking a dumb question, I didn't mean to :)

EDIT: My action URL is in the same folder as my HTML file.

Comment: The browser would not allow you to access the local file system, since this would cause a security issue. That is you won't be able to do anything with local files like `F:/HTML_practice_results.txt`.

Comment: Oh, thank you. So is this impossible to do with HTML? Or would I need another browser or something?

Comment: You need to setup a web server locally on your machine... Instead of accessing the HTML page as F:/ -- whaeaver, it would be something like: http://localhost:8888.  Lookup XAMPP or a MAMP for easy to get started web servers.

Comment: You could host your html files on a simple HTTP server like IIS or apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are loading this file directly without running it through a web server, you won't have the same access to your root folder of your web server, and everything has to be referenced from its relative location.  In your example you must have results_page.txt residing in the same exact folder as whereever this HTML file lives for this to work.

Try setting up XAMPP or a web server so that you can actually use a server-side language to read GET & POSTED data.